# tensorflow-gpu on a Docker of host running on radeon 560?

Tags: docker, tensorflow, nvidia, google-colaboratory

I am trying out tensorflow for deep learning, but for GPU support, tensorflow needs Nvidia GPU, but I have a Radeon 560. Is there any way of running tensorflow GPU in a Docker container? I couldn't wrap my head around Docker. Are there any other possibilities other than using Colab or Docker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official tensorflow-gpu docker images at this time only support NVIDIA gpus and host running the NVIDIA cuda-driver. In order to use an AMD GPU, you need to use a version of TensorFlow built with ROCm support. Google for "tensorflow ROCm" and you'll find some pages on how to do this. The best link is probably:

https://github.com/ROCmSoftwarePlatform/tensorflow-upstream